# Take different typeface from a ttc Android

Tags: android, fonts, android-fonts

in my application I must use a custom type of font in a file .ttc . This file conteins different type of typeface (normal, bold, ...). With this code:

```
textDetails.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttc"));
```

I can take one type of typeface. There is a method to take all the typeface?

Comment: I would not be surprised if Android does not support TrueType Collection (TTC) files.

Comment: If I try to use a ttc the program take and use correctly one type of font

Comment: Sorry, let me rephrase: I would not be surprised if Android does not *fully* support TrueType Collection (TTC) files.

Comment: It is possible to extract ttf from ttc with tools like https://transfonter.org/ttc-unpack

Answer (score 3):

You can set the style to access the bold and italic typefaces:
[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface(android.graphics.Typeface, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTypeface%28android.graphics.Typeface,%20int%29)

Try this:

```
textDetails.setTypeface(Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/font.ttc"), Typeface.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load specific font from TTC file using Typeface.Builder (API level 26). This is a snippet from comments in the Typeface source code:

```
Typeface.Builder buidler = new Typeface.Builder(getAssets(), "your_font_file.ttc");
builder.setTtcIndex(2);  // Set index of font collection.
Typeface typeface = builder.build();
```

Only use `setTtcIndex()` method if you *know* the file is TTC.

Source: [Android Source Code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/graphics/java/android/graphics/Typeface.java#286)